# Незакрытые теги на html5

Tags: html5

При использовании доктайпа html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` rак правильно писать теги, у которых нет закрывающего тега, например

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<img src="" alt="">
```

нужно ли в конце писать слэш?

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<img src="" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и так, и так. Однако, для элементов, которые могут содержать content, результат может быть разным, конечно (представьте себе, что будет, если вы не закроете `<a>`). Вот пост на эту тему с подробностями (на английском): http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Обновление: вот отличный ответ на [братском ресурсе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/276994):

> На HTML 5, `<foo />` значит `<foo>`. Слеш является просто синтаксическим сахаром для любителей XML. Синтаксис со слешем поддерживается, но это вовсе не "самозакрывающийся тег"! Разница важна, поскольку (по крайней мере в синтаксисе HTML) `<div />` означает `<div>` на HTML 5, а не `<div></div>`, как в XHTML.

Comment: я спрашиваю именно про теги, у которых нет закрывающего тега.

Comment: @Heidel: смотрите в обновление ответа

Comment: @Heidel: для тегов, у которых нет закрывающего, должно быть всё равно.